# Game crashes when changing scenes, pointer being freed not allocated

Tags: cocos2d-x, exc-bad-access

I am switching scenes when my character wins or loses the game. I get a message saying a pointer being freed was not allocated.

Sometimes, the game does not crash and it goes back to the game view. But sometimes the game crashes in the main on this line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
```

the error being "bad access";

I switch to the end screen using the CCdirector:

```
cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(GameWon::scene());
```

Then in the GameWon.cpp I create a new game scene to start a new game:

```
  cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(Controller::scene());
```

No idea what causes this problem. The weird thing is that, it doesn't always crash on the simulator. Any tips?

**edit**

So I found out what the problem is, I just don't know why it's a problem. Apparently the destructor of my Controller is called when I create a new scene. In this destructor I free my model object:

```
Controller::~Controller()
{
    free(pModel);
}
```

When I don't free the model object it works like a charm. However, in the init of my constructor I do this:

```
 pModel = Model::create();
```

So I'm not sure why the pModel would be a pointer that is being freed, but not allocated?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you did not retain retain your pModel object. Create function usually autoreleases the object and if you do not retain it, it will be deleted by the time you call "free(pModel)" in the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

you need not to free your `pModel` object manually in the destructor as in the create function  the object being created is added to the `autorelease pool` . So what happens here is that first when the autorelease pool drains it automatically deallocates the memory allocated to the `pModel` . And when the controller's destructor is called `free(pModel);` tries to free the memory which is already freed.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace scene, The destructor of previous scene is called. If you free the object created with create() function of cocos, as it’s already added in autorelease pool managed by cocos, pool tries to release (delete) already deleted(in destructor using free) pointer. so, Don’t use manual delete to cocos objects created using create functions.